# Unable to dispatch actions with Redux

Tags: typescript, firebase, redux, react-redux

I'm using Firebase to handle the authentication in my React-Redux application, but I can't dispatch all intended actions.

At the moment, I have 6 actions to dispatch: `REGISTER_USER_SUCCESS`, `REGISTER_USER_FAIL`, `LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS`, `LOGIN_USER_FAIL`, `LOGOUT_USER_SUCCESS`, and `LOGOUT_USER_FAIL`. I can dispatch all actions but the ones related to user logout, i.e. `LOGOUT_USER_SUCCESS` and `LOGOUT_USER_FAIL`.

When I click on the `Nav.Link` to logout, in **NavigationBar.tsx**, it logs in my console the string "LOG NAV", but anything within the code **logoutUser.ts** is logged in the console ("LOG1" and "LOG2"), which means that the function `logoutUser` was actually not executed...

Here is the code I've done so far:

**logoutUser.ts**

```js
// Import components, functions, types, variables, and styles
import { Dispatch } from 'redux'
import { auth } from '../firebase'

// Types and interfaces
interface ILogoutUserSuccess {
    type: typeof LOGOUT_USER_SUCCESS
}

interface ILogoutUserFail {
    type: typeof LOGOUT_USER_FAIL
}

export type TDispatchLogoutUser = ILogoutUserSuccess | ILogoutUserFail

// Action types
export const LOGOUT_USER_SUCCESS = 'LOGOUT_USER_SUCCESS'
export const LOGOUT_USER_FAIL = 'LOGOUT_USER_FAIL'

// Actions
export default function logoutUser() {
    return async (dispatch: Dispatch<TDispatchLogoutUser>) => {
        try {
            console.log('LOG1')
            await auth.signOut()

            dispatch({
                type: LOGOUT_USER_SUCCESS
            })
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('LOG2')
            dispatch({
                type: LOGOUT_USER_FAIL
            })

            console.log(error)
        }
    }
}
```

**NavigationBar.tsx**

```js
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { Navbar, Nav } from 'react-bootstrap'
import logoutUser from '../actions/logoutUser'
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'

export function NavigationBar() {
    const history = useHistory()

    function handleLogout() {
        logoutUser()
        console.log('LOG NAV')
        // history.push('/user/login/')
    }

    return (
        <Navbar className="mb-2 mb-md-3 d-flex flex-column flex-md-row justify-content-between shadow">
            <Navbar.Brand className="ml-2 font-size">
                <b className="font-weight-bold">Rodolfo</b> Kirch Veiga
            </Navbar.Brand>
            <Nav className="mr-2">
                <Nav.Link href="/">Home</Nav.Link>
                <Nav.Link href="/resume/">Resume</Nav.Link>
                <Nav.Link href="/projects/">Projects</Nav.Link>
                <Nav.Link href="/blog/">Blog</Nav.Link>
                <Nav.Link href="/contact/">Contact</Nav.Link>
                <Nav.Link href="/user/">Profile</Nav.Link>
                <Nav.Link href="/user/register/">Register</Nav.Link>
                <Nav.Link href="/user/login/">Login</Nav.Link>
                <Nav.Link onClick={handleLogout}>Logout</Nav.Link>
            </Nav>
        </Navbar>
    )
}

export default connect(null, { logoutUser })(NavigationBar)
```

---

I know Redux is a huge lot of boilerplate, but the code is pretty straight forward. I hope someone can help me with that...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

After hours staring the code I found the error myself. In the navigation bar I have forgotten to set the function `logoutUser` as a **prop**. Therefore, the solution follows:

```js
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { Navbar, Nav } from 'react-bootstrap'
import logoutUser from '../actions/logoutUser'
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'

interface INavigationBarProps {
    logoutUser: Function
}

export function NavigationBar({ logoutUser }: INavigationBarProps) {
    const history = useHistory()

    function handleLogout() {
        logoutUser()
        history.push('/user/login/')
    }

    return (
        <Navbar className="mb-2 mb-md-3 d-flex flex-column flex-md-row justify-content-between shadow">
            <Navbar.Brand className="ml-2 font-size">
                <b className="font-weight-bold">Rodolfo</b> Kirch Veiga
            </Navbar.Brand>
            <Nav className="mr-2">
                <Nav.Link href="/">Home</Nav.Link>
                <Nav.Link href="/resume/">Resume</Nav.Link>
                <Nav.Link href="/projects/">Projects</Nav.Link>
                <Nav.Link href="/blog/">Blog</Nav.Link>
                <Nav.Link href="/contact/">Contact</Nav.Link>
                <Nav.Link href="/user/">Profile</Nav.Link>
                <Nav.Link href="/user/register/">Register</Nav.Link>
                <Nav.Link href="/user/login/">Login</Nav.Link>
                <Nav.Link onClick={handleLogout}>Logout</Nav.Link>
            </Nav>
        </Navbar>
    )
}

export default connect(null, { logoutUser })(NavigationBar)
```